# How place two or more 3D assets in ARCore using Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I just want to have two buttons #1, #2 on canvas and after plane detection when I select button #1 and tap on screen one 3D asset should be placed and when I click on button #2 and tap on screen second 3D asset should be placed and the previous asset needs to be removed.
At a time one asset needs to be placed and when selecting another asset the previously placed asset needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the [HelloAR Example](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/blob/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/HelloAR/Scripts/HelloARController.cs)? There you have: `public GameObject AndyAndroidPrefab;` This will be placed on touch. So you can modify that code from the example project to fit your needs.

You can add two public GameObjects where you place your 3D assets and remove the AndyAndroidPrefab asset.

```
public GameObject obj1_prefab;
public GameObject obj2_prefab;
```

Then you cann add a bool variable that shows you which button is clicked.

```
private bool firstBtnClicked = true;
```

Then you can make two public void functions wich handles the button clicks:

```
public void firstButtonClick()
{
    firstBtnClicked = true;
}

public void secondButtonClick()
{
    firstBtnClicked = false;
}
```

Then you can add the function to your canvas buttons:
[image]

Then you have to make changes where you [instantiate the object:](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/blob/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/HelloAR/Scripts/HelloARController.cs#L119)

```
 //Test if already an object exists and delete it:
 if (GameObject.Find("Anchor/myobject") != null)
 {
     GameObject parentanchor = GameObject.Find("Anchor/myobject").transform.parent.gameObject;
     Destroy(parentanchor);
  }

  GameObject obj = null;
  if (firstBtnClicked == true)
  {
      // Instantiate first Asset model at the hit pose.
      obj = Instantiate(obj1_prefab, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);
  }
  else
  {
      // Second button clicked: Instantiate second Asset model at the hit pose.
      obj = Instantiate(obj2_prefab, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);
  }

  // Compensate for the hitPose rotation facing away from the raycast (i.e. camera).
  obj.transform.Rotate(0, k_ModelRotation, 0, Space.Self);
  obj.name = "myobject";
  // Create an anchor to allow ARCore to track the hitpoint as understanding of the physical
  // world evolves.
  var anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

  // Make the object model a child of the anchor.
  obj.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
```

So now if you click button one you select your first object and after a touch on the screen the first asset is placed. When you click on the second button you'll place the second object on screen touch.